Error: Write token not found in Sanity write-client configuration (Next.js project)
 ✓ Starting...
 ⚠ Configuration with next.config.ts is currently an experimental feature, use with caution.
 ○ Compiling /instrumentation ...
 ✓ Compiled /instrumentation in 3.7s (865 modules)
 ✓ Ready in 8.6s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 14.2s (4673 modules)
 ⨯ sanity\lib\write-client.ts (15:9) @ eval
 ⨯ Error: Write token not found.
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./sanity/lib/write-client.ts:21:11)
    at __webpack_require__.a (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./sanity/lib/write-client.ts:1:21)
    at (rsc)/./sanity/lib/write-client.ts (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\app\(root)\page.js:1023:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./auth.ts:13:82)
    at __webpack_require__.a (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./auth.ts:1:21)
    at (rsc)/./auth.ts (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\app\(root)\page.js:825:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./components/Navbar.tsx:15:63)
    at __webpack_require__.a (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./components/Navbar.tsx:1:21)
    at (rsc)/./components/Navbar.tsx (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\app\(root)\page.js:836:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/(root)/layout.tsx:17:76)
    at __webpack_require__.a (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:108:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/(root)/layout.tsx:1:21)
    at (rsc)/./app/(root)/layout.tsx (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\app\(root)\page.js:600:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (E:\Github\yc_directory\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at async getLayoutOrPageModule (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:10688)
    at async createComponentTreeInternal (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:17321)
    at async E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:22038
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async createComponentTreeInternal (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:21262)
    at async getRSCPayload (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:71871)
    at async renderToStream (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:91401)
    at async renderToHTMLOrFlightImpl (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:157:84078)
    at async doRender (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1564:34)
    at async responseGenerator (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1807:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1851:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:2223:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:2261:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:973:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:281:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:866:17)  
    at async E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:377:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:157:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:374:24)
    at async invokeRender (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:183:21)
    at async handleRequest (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:360:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:384:13)     
    at async Server.requestListener (E:\Github\yc_directory\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:142:13) {
  page: '/'
}
  13 |
  14 | if (!writeClient.config().token) {
> 15 |   throw new Error("Write token not found.");
     |         ^
  16 | }
  17 |
 ○ Compiling /_error ...
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 3.5s (5117 modules)

This is an open source code from the Github. https://github.com/adrianhajdin/yc_directory               I'm working on this Next.js project that uses Sanity as a CMS. However, I'm encountering an error related to the configuration of the Sanity client. Here is the error message I'm seeing in my terminal:
Because I just need  to create a env file and get the key. Then this will run correctly.
javascript
Error: Write token not found
at eval (sanity\lib\write-client.ts:15:8)
What I Have Done:
I created a Write Token in the Sanity dashboard and added it to my .env file:
makefile
SANITY_WRITE_TOKEN=your_generated_token
enter image description here
And I tried several options here. It is not working.

"enter image description here" is not a good description of an image.  You should [edit] your question and describe, in words, what information you hope the image will give the reader.
